# Height of window resizing on tab close for Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

The tab bar automatically appear when there is more than 1 tab. When down to just 1 tab, the tab bar would disappear and the window resizes in height. The height is shorter by height of the disappeared tab bar.

Is there a way to prevent this resizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
:set showtabline=2 "always show tabs, even if there is only one
```

Comment: This works but is there an option of resizing it correctly when the tab bar disappears?

Comment: @Ronnie Liew: at least i haven't found one.